# flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1188)] Could not locate ImageTextureEntry class

Tags: flutter

flutter version 3.16.9;
[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1188)] Could not locate ImageTextureEntry class
[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/library_loader.cc(26)] Check failed: result.
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 16858 (pool-23-thread-), pid 10471 (com.uzi.arng)

---

Build fingerprint: 'samsung/beyond1qltezc/beyond1q:11/RP1A.200720.012/G9730ZCS6FULZ:user/release-keys'
Revision: '17'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2024-03-22 14:56:21+0800
pid: 10471, tid: 16858, name: pool-23-thread-  >>> com.x.x <<<
uid: 12783
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/library_loader.cc(26)] Check failed: result.
'
x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000041da  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000006c787a5bf0
x4  0000007025556000  x5  0000007025556000  x6  0000007025556000  x7  0000000002b85e44
x8  00000000000000f0  x9  a171530579d2836d  x10 0000000000000000  x11 ffffffc0fffffbdf
x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000065fd2b95  x14 0000000000000000  x15 0000c0780dd419fe
x16 000000701f3ccc80  x17 000000701f3ac4c0  x18 0000006c780a2000  x19 00000000000028e7
x20 00000000000041da  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 0000006c775df000  x23 0000006c775df000
x24 0000006c76f1d940  x25 0000000000000000  x26 b400006d9dc3f8a0  x27 b400006e0dc1a9e0
x28 b400006dedc51450  x29 0000006c787a5c70
lr  000000701f35bef8  sp  0000006c787a5bd0  pc  000000701f35bf24  pst 0000000000000000
backtrace:
#00 pc 000000000004ef24  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164) (BuildId: a9be8f8e3ba7df39d3fe4858932ef34b)
#01 pc 000000000036fac4  /data/app/~~7r3bJZ0LLsZb3ttc6rLEhw==/com.x.x-156bAkJe26ASc9Le6nXfYw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 906784233a7115d633b9295589a1b16a2329b46a)
#02 pc 000000000039e24c  /data/app/~~7r3bJZ0LLsZb3ttc6rLEhw==/com.x.x-156bAkJe26ASc9Le6nXfYw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: 906784233a7115d633b9295589a1b16a2329b46a)
#03 pc 0000000000383188  /data/app/~~7r3bJZ0LLsZb3ttc6rLEhw==/com.x.x-156bAkJe26ASc9Le6nXfYw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (JNI_OnLoad+2120) (BuildId: 906784233a7115d633b9295589a1b16a2329b46a)
#04 pc 0000000000376940  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&, _jobject*, _jclass*,

Have you encountered the same problem and how did you solve it?